# How to reset dns record from cloudflare

Tags: dns, cloudflare

I was added a domain in cloudfalre

and added some A records.

and after some time i removed the domain from cloudflare

and now today i have re added the domain, it is not showing the records in dashboard that is previously add

but it is showing in lookup

how can i remove all the records that not showing in dashboard ??

Answer (score 0):

You may not understand what Cloudflare is.

The A records that are in your dashboard is your real server's IP address.

A server that serves your website is your real server.

Now, you used Cloudflare, so Cloudflare serves your website.

The look-up is Cloudflare IP.

Visitor diagram:
Visitor -> Cloudflare -> Original Server

When you look-up, this is the diagram: Look-up -> Cloudflare